# Mongoose query of getting item take to much time

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, optimization, mongodb-query, query-optimization

i want to get the item list from database using these query param but it take almost 10-15 second to getting me the response and i have total 500 record in item model
Purpose : get all the items with price greater then equal to 100 and less then equal to 1000 also if req.query.locality present and if req.query.locality == islamabad or rawalpindi get both becuase rawalpindi and islamabad in twin citites

```
let query = {
  $and: [{ price: { $gte: 100} }, { price: { $lte: 1000} }]
};
if (req.query.locality) {
  if (
    req.query.locality == "Islamabad" ||
    req.query.locality == "Rawalpindi"
  )
    query.city = { $in: ["Islamabad", "Rawalpindi"] };
  else query.city = req.query.locality;
}
const items = await Item.find(query).sort({ _id: -1 });
```

I also make indexes of these two fileds but api response is still take to much time

```
ItemSchema.index({ city: 1, price: 1 });
const Item = mongoose.model("items", ItemSchema);
```

Query planner execution stats

```
    {
  queryPlanner: {
    plannerVersion: 1,
    namespace: 'bakra-online.items',
    indexFilterSet: false,
    parsedQuery: [Object],
    winningPlan: [Object],
    rejectedPlans: [Array]
  },
  executionStats: {
    executionSuccess: true,
    nReturned: 155,
    executionTimeMillis: 1,
    totalKeysExamined: 155,
    totalDocsExamined: 155,
    executionStages: [Object],
    allPlansExecution: [Array]
  },
  serverInfo: {
    host: 'ip-.......',
    port: 27017,
    version: '3.6.3',
  },
  ok: 1
}
```

Comment: Obtain query plans with execution stats, add to the question.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: I do not see query plans or execution stats.

Comment: done sir.. sorry i did not understand the question

Comment: That says your query executed in  1 millisecond.

Comment: let me confirm sir

Comment: 200OK
3 m 5.64 s
78.23 KB

Comment: postman response time is 3min.. even on browser it give response in a sec but loading still their for more then 1 min .. http://100.25.147.148:8080/v1/item/list?locality=Islamabad